# django-tables2 exclude & field not working

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm new to django and stumbling through creating my first site. I'm using django-tables2 to display a table and it appears to be working (the table shows up, it's sortable).

Except I can't seem to customize anything. Exclude, field and sequence don't work. Can't change column verbose names.

TABLE:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from sl_overview.models import DailyslSumm

class slsummTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = DailyslSumm
        exclude = ('index')
```

VIEW:

```
class sl_summ(SingleTableView):

    model = DailyslSumm
    context_object_name = 'slsummdb'
    table_class = slsummTable
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table slsummdb %}
```

The exclude in the code above doesn't work. The column is still there. Using field doesn't adjust columns either. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must make sure `exclude` is a tuple (or list), and not a string. If you use parenthesis with one string, the resulting value will be a string, not a tuple like you might expect:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
>>> ('foo')
'foo'
>>> ('foo', )
('foo',)
>>>
```

In your case, you should add a comma after `'index'` like this:

```
class slsummTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = DailyslSumm
        exclude = ('index', )  # <- note the extra comma here
```

Comment: This, combined with properly creating the table class, worked. Thanks!